# Windows batch file "was unexpected this time".

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

```
@echo off
pause
set /a x=1
set /a n=0
set /p x_end=x (End)=
:loop
cls
set /a n=n+1
set /a x=x+n+1
set /a students=n+2
echo x=%x%, n=%n%, x (End)=%x_end%
if (%x%=%x_end% goto end)
goto loop
:end
echo Answer: x (End)=%x%, Students=%students%, n (end)=%n%
echo.
echo Click Anything To Exit...
pause > nul
exit
```

---

The "if" line is producing a message that what you put in the %x_end% variable "was unexpected this time".

Comment: Too lazy to check now, but your closing bracket should be before the `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
rem pause
set /a x=1
set /a n=0
set /p x_end=x ^(End^)=
rem ensure %x_end% will result to a number 
set /a "x_end=x_end"
:loop
  echo cls
  set /a n=n+1
  set /a x=x+n+1
  set /a students=n+2
  echo x=%x%, n=%n%, x ^(End^)=%x_end%
  rem pause >nul
  if %x% GTR %x_end% goto end
goto loop
:end
echo Answer: x ^(End^)=%x%, Students=%students%, n ^(end^)=%n%
echo(
echo Click Anything To Exit...
pause > nul
rem exit
```

There are next improvements in above code snippet:

- merely for debugging purposes

  - some `rem`  (initial `pause`, final `exit`);
  - `echo cls` instead of `cls`;
- important

  - `set /a "x_end=x_end"` to ensure `%x_end%` will result to a number for whatever user's input;
  - `if` [valid syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html): use `GTR` (>, greater than) or `GEQ` (>=, greater than or equal);
  - because of [parentheses special meaning in batch scripting](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html), all opening `(` and closing `)` are [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in all occurrences where those should be used literally (`echo` and `set /p`). Trying `if 1==1 (echo (inner) parentheses)` will show that it could matter. Although this does not matter in *given* code snippet, it's worthwhile as a matter of general principle.